# Java: Bitwise operations on booleans that are returned from Methods

Tags: java, boolean, operators

I'm looking at the following code snippet

```
bResult |= purgeDataForDIG(protocol);
```

The variable  bResult is of type boolean.

Am I correct in assuming that the return of the method `purgeDataForDig` is OR'd with `bResult` and the result is then written back into `bResult`?

thanks
Paul.

Comment: Why not simply test it yourself?

Comment: Or write "java pipe assignment" into google. Which is exactly what you are looking at. Do your homework before asking questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct,

The above code snippet is functionally the same as:

```
res = purgeDataForDIG(protocol);
bResult = bResult | res;
```